# Periodically download file from my dropbox account

Tags: python, selenium, download, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have the django application, which needs refresh some data. This data should be downloaded from my dropbox account (file name and path is the same each time). How can I implement this?

I start with using dropbox api, create application, etc - but this method has one big defect - it needs user go to the generated link and authorize to dropbox account.  But I need automatic work, script should be executed by cron each day without userinteraction.

I think about using Selenium to open this link, enter login and password, confirm using application. But I also think this is hard way, should be another way:-)

Or maybe I can simply generate link to file one time and then use it every time I want to download file?

Comment: Do you need access to the file to be private? Else you can just put it in the public folder and fetch it with curl.

Comment: Yes, access should be private.

Comment: Or maybe I can simply generate link to file one time and then use it every time I want to download file? I'm aftraid of link will expired...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the API and connect with pre-authorized access token which you authorized manually once (as opposed to having the user authorize their own account). You could then download the file from your account, but be sure not to revoke the access token, e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/applications .

If you do just need to download files though, using a shared link may be easier:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/167/en
https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en

They don't expire, but they can be revoked via https://www.dropbox.com/links .

Or if you prefer to use the Public folder, same idea:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en